# wildcard data into multidimensional array using regex

Tags: php, html, regex

so i am getting the contents of an html file, and i want pull specific information from within html elements into a multidimensional array.  the issue is i do not have much experience with regex.

there are many artists in a list, and this is how each artist is formatted.

```
<li class="artist"><a href="*I NEED THIS PATH*">*AND THIS TEXT*</a></li>
```

this is what i have so far:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('somefile.txt'); 
$artists = preg_split('/^<li class="artist"><a href="(.*)">(.*)<\/a><\/li>$/', $contents);
$artistInfo = array();

foreach( $artists as $artist ) :

    preg_match('/href="(.*)">/', $element, $matchPath); // link paths
    preg_match('/">(.*)<\/a><\/li>/', $element, $matchName); // artist names

    array_push( $artistInfo, array( $matchName, $matchPath ) ); // put info into array

endforeach;

print_r($artistInfo);
```

the preg_split is not working how i hoped, so it's throwing everything else off, but i don't know if my preg_match expressions are right either. please help!

Comment: Keep in mind `.*` is very greedy and will process to and end of a string before backtracking. You may instead want to do something like `([^"]*)` for the link instead of `(.*)`. Or use Dom like the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a regex for this. [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) is your friend:

```
$artistInfo = array();
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( file_get_contents('somefile.txt') );

$xPath = new DOMXpath($dom);

foreach ( $xPath->query('//li[@class="artist"]/a') as $anchor ) {
    $artistInfo[] = array(
        $anchor->textContent,
        $anchor->getAttribute('href')
    );
}
```

See it here in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/NziHBo